# Contract(WETHER) back to ether

Tags: web3js, ether

I converted my ether to wether by sending ether to the contract (wether).

`var send = web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase,to:contract_address, value:web3.toWei(0.05, "ether")});`

Now I want to convert back wether to ether. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What contract are you using?  If it's a normal wrapped ether contract, usually there is a withdraw that looks something like this:

```
function withdraw(uint wad) public {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= wad);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= wad;
    msg.sender.transfer(wad);
    Withdrawal(msg.sender, wad);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the value line `toWei`, it only moves the decimal point for a more user friendly experience. You can't have floating point numbers when talking about the value of Ether. For example 0.05 Ether is equivalent to 50000000000000000. You don't need to convert the Wei back to Ether as it is not a problem that exists